# AWS IAM: Unable to create additional Access Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have two access keys in IAM: One active and one inactive.

Since I have forgotten my Secret Access Key I want to create a new set of credentials, but the **Create access key** button is greyed out. I don't know how to make new or how to retrieve my Secret Access Key.

Answer (score 80):

You need to delete, one of the existing keys, since IAM allows only two access keys maximum for IAM user.

Comment: They should probably explain that in the UI not just arbitrarily grey out functionality.  Could be a hover-tip or under the `Access Keys` description.  That is, if AWS is interested in being user friendly.

Comment: This was helpful as AWS doesn't say there's a limit (as ProGirlXOXO says above) and that led me to 30 min of head scratching trying to figure out, thinking I was doing something wrong. Removing the old (and in my case unused) key did the trick and instantly the button became available to create another.

Comment: Agree with other comments here. It's an absurd fail that this isn't made clear in the IAM UI. If you can make 2 you'd generally assume you can make a 3rd. Expect better from Amazon/AWS!